# github packages: peer not authenticated

Tags: jenkins, github, gradle

I have gradle configuration for `github packages` similar to this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'GitHubPackages'
        url = uri('https://maven.pkg.github.com/whatever/whatever')
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("GITHUB_PKG_USER")
            password = System.getenv("GITHUB_PKG_TOKEN")
        }
    }
}
```

And some library which I read from that repo. I've noticed our jenkins build sometimes failed with:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not download library-name.jar 
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/correct-path-to-jar.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://github-registry-files.githubusercontent.com/275167411/e47ffc80-8d5d-11eb-81c7-80fd7fa422bd?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCODYLSA52GIFG5T%2F20210330%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210330T154314Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=67765f831023f46bf93d2a9354e2cd38913d87481281975dadd7e7d26a63b953'.
            > peer not authenticated
```

And then after rebuild it just works. Linked xml looks this way:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<X-Amz-Expires>300</X-Amz-Expires>
<Expires>2021-03-30T15:48:14Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2021-03-31T10:31:25Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>D2AF221VHNYTPTA3</RequestId>
<HostId>JEzBk1i9ZfzhyU3ab7TMtHozZ5l6BQvjPD+BzWlbMJEToTgC1UuGeMUMoBtUSjnvu3mlpkTDN9s=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any ideas what is it about ?

gradle - 6.6.1
java - 11

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was receiving the same error with maven and openjdk-11 when running in Travis-CI. The error does not happen when running with oracle jdk 8, so I ended up switching to run maven with oracle jdk 8. It might be a side-effect of JDK switcher in travis CI, or something else.